# Adding jscolor class to bootstrap navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jscolor

I am trying to make boootstrap navbar work with jscolor like this button bellow.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jscolor/2.0.4/jscolor.min.js"></script>
<button
    class="jscolor {valueElement:null,value:'333'}"
    style="border:1px solid black">
    Color
</button>
```

Here is the navbar which i am trying to connect with jscolor:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jscolor/2.0.4/jscolor.min.js"></script>
<script src="jscolor.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top jscolor {valueElement:null,value:'333'}">
```

Comment: Have you tried **[this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44069862/how-can-i-make-jscolor-colorpicker-to-work-on-a-div)**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help, `z-index` is needed so that navbar would not overlap color picker.

```js
var nav = document.getElementById("navbar");
var navColor = document.getElementById("nav-color");

nav.addEventListener("click", function(){
 navColor.jscolor.show();
});
```

```css
#navbar {
  z-index: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jscolor/2.0.4/jscolor.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jscolor/2.0.4/jscolor.min.js"></script>

<input id="nav-color" class="jscolor {styleElement:'navbar',value:'333'}" type="hidden">
<nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top ">
</nav>
```

Comment: Great answer. Thank you! Sorry for being so late with responding.

Comment: Happy to help! No need to apologize.

Comment: that will cause a problem when you add menu items, adding a button to change color is much better

Comment: Of course it will show color picker on every click. I like your implementation, but I think that adding a button is not an answer to this specific question.

Answer (score 1):

you can add a button to change color

[a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vz21x6kr/)

```
function update(jscolor) {
 document.getElementById('navbar').style.backgroundColor = '#' + jscolor
}
```